# Create contactorders in MS CRM 4.0 through the SDK

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm using .NET and the CRM SDK to manage salesorders in CRM. However, I want to be able to add contacts to salesorder. This should be possible using records in the intersect table contactorders.
What is the procedure for adding contactorders? I tried creating a Dynamic Entity of the contactorder type, but I get the error that Create doesn't support contactorders.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the SetRelated message.

From the SDK:

> **SetRelated** Use this message to create
>   a relationship between a sales order
>   (order) and a contact.  The
>   information that is needed to relate
>   the two instances is specified in the
>   TargetRelatedSalesOrderToContact
>   class.
>   [Order (salesorder) Entity Capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928269.aspx)